# How can I give "type:richtext" to the schema inside the schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 files: service.admin.js and service.entity.js
Since I wanted to write the description in 3 languages, I created the DescriptionShema. but I want to make DescriptionShema "type:richtext". How can I do this in service.admin.js?
This is my code :
service.entity.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DescriptionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   AZ: String,
   ENG: String,
   RU: String,
});

const ServiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   description: {
      type: DescriptionSchema,
      required: true,
   }
});

const Service = mongoose.model('Service', ServiceSchema);

module.exports = { ServiceSchema, Service };
```

serivce.admin.js :

```
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');
const { Service } = require('./service.entity');

/** @type {AdminBro.ResourceOptions} */
const options = {
   properties: {
      _id: {
         isVisible: false,
      }
   }
};

module.exports = {
   options,
   resource: Service,
};
```

How can I change the type of DescriptionShema inside properties?

Comment: Hey, first of all it would be best if you upgrade to new AdminJS version. Recently we've change the richText lib.

Comment: Secondly I'm not sure what you want to achieve. How your dashboard should look in the end?